# Javascript object property isn't displayed but can be accessed

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, middleware

i'm creating a custom express middleware to handle errors thrown by mongoose.
the `error` has a `message` property:

```js
//works as intended
console.log(error.message); //E11000 duplicate key error collection
```

but when i want to send the entire object, the `message` property doesn't show up:

```js
res.status(400).json(error);
/*
recieved response:
{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "name": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "name": "Some Name"
    }
}
*/
```

destructuring doesn't work either:

```js
res.status(400).json({ ...error });
//same response as before
```

it doesn't show it in Object.keys() either:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(error)); //[ 'index', 'code', 'keyPattern', 'keyValue' ]
```

but this statement is true:

```js
console.log("message" in error); //true
```

i don't know why it behaves this way but what is the workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `message` property on `error` object is `non-enumerable`. If a property is `non-enumerable`, it cannot be serialised (`res.json` serialises the input JSON), won't appear in `Object.keys` or get `destructured`.

Your best bet is either to explicitly set the `enumerable` as `true` on `error.message`, or copy the `error.message` on some other key inside `error` object.

```
// For initialisation 
Object.defineProperty(error, 'message', {enumerable: true, value: ''});

//OR 
const errorMessage = error.message;
error.customMessage = errorMessage;
// Now use error.customMessage instead of error.message 

// OR
// Create a new object with the above retrieved error.message

const customError = {...error, message: customMessage};
// use customError object now
res.status(400).json(customError);
```

More details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: this made it work:
`Object.defineProperty(error, 'message', {enumerable: true, value: error.message});`
thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should use :

```
let message = `${Object.values(error.keyValue)} is duplicated/already exists, please choose another one` 
console.log(message) // name is duplicated/already exists, please choose another one
```